# Как правильно написать: "расположено" или "расположены"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно написать: "на территории города расположено 215 объектов" или "расположены 215 объектов"?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос непростой, почитайте в справочниках раздел **"Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте)"**